# In Word, find synonyms when using track changes

Tags: microsoft-word

MS Word (2010) has a nice feature that you can right click a word and then find a list of synonyms. However, when track changes is on, in a changed part of the document, the right click (context) menu doesn't give this option: instead I get a context menu specific to track changes (e.g., with option to accept change or whatever). Unfortunately, I still need a thesaurus, even when changes are tracked. How can I get synonyms back in my tracked content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the **Review** tab, in the **Tracking** group, set the **Display for Review** field to **No Markup**, or, in the **Show Markup** field, clear the selection for **Insertions and Deletions**.

Either way, you'll no longer see which text has been inserted and deleted, but you'll be able to use the **Synonyms** command.